# Eclipse Modelling Tools - Initialize date

Tags: eclipse, eol

I have an eol file and one class has an EDate attribute, how do I give a value to this in code?

```
var obj: new Obj;
obj.date = ...
```

I want to give a specific date, not a current date. I want something like this: "2024-05-23".